*.bat File command line redering V 4.2 LTS
Since version 2.9, we have been working with command line rendering, embedded in a *.bat file, to process our blender scenes. This is no longer possible with 4.2 LTS. When the first scene in the *.bat file has been processed, the next one does not start. No error message, just a stop of the rendering process. Has the syntax changed? By the way, we are working on Windows. I can't say whether the problem also occurs on other operating systems.
